# migrating ContainerOS (CoreOS) alpha from etcd2 to etcd3

Tags: coreos, etcd, etcd3

I have Container Linux by CoreOS 1353.1.0 installed and it uses etcd2 by default. I can't even find an etcd3 service file (`systemctl | grep etcd` only shows `etcd2.service`).

I wanna play with etcd3. especially because it's the default storage backend for kubernetes 1.6.

is there any way (easy or hard) to migrate from etcd2 to etcd3? when I say migrate.. I don't mind recofiguring my ignition file and reinstalling the all OS.

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

how come ContainerOS Alpha doesn't come with etcd3?!?!

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use `etcd-member.service` to start a container image with any version that I want. it's cool !:)

more info at https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/getting-started-with-etcd.html#setting-up-etcd